# instagram iphone hooks MEDIA ID?

Tags: ios, instagram

I want to open instagram with the picture from my app.

In their [API](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)
it says to use the MEDIA ID. I am unaware of a media ID. I know of Asset Representation URL form the ALasset library. Does anyone know what they are refering to?

Answer (score 0):

The media ID comes from the Instagram API for the media that was uploaded to instagram. Usually something on the lines like 448979387270691659_45818965. I believe you can grab it in the browser if you go to the media view in your browser and then use developer tools to see the atttribute